# Mutliple CSS pseudo selectors in Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, pseudo-element

Specifically this:

```
p:first-child:first-letter {font-size:48px;}
```

Works in all browsers (even IE8 for crying out loud) but not Firefox (v.10.02)

Anybody know a CSS or javascript work-around? The only thing I can think of doing to achieve what I want (a drop cap in the first paragraph) is to dynamically wrap that first character with span tags. But surely there's a better way?

Comment: Strangely, this works for me in 10.0.2: http://jsfiddle.net/PY7jB/

Comment: Alexander, x539: it looks like it may be related to jQuery 1.7.1 - I noticed you both had mootools framework selected on jsfiddle. I flipped to jquery 1.7.1 and hello little F:( jQuery 1.6.4 works though :)

Comment: Interestingly enough: I changed style from FireBug here, but that change didn't work until I disabled and enabled `border-collapse` property for table selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
p:first-letter {font-size:48px;}
p + p:first-letter {font-size:1rem}
```

that uses the new `rem` unit, which is [root em, for IE>8](http://caniuse.com/#search=rem) you would have to put in your root font size manually.

or you can use JQuery like

```
   $('p:first-child').addClass('first-child');
```

and change your css to

```
p.first-child:first-letter { font-size:48px}
```

Comment: Bingo! neat CSS solution Jkirchartz. I'd already tried your jquery solution but result was the same. You'll see above that, following some help via jsfiddle, the problem is related specifically to jQuery 1.7.1 and Firefox. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: that fiddle worked on my FF, but I love all the different ways there are to skin a cat

Answer (score 0):

I think p doesn't have any children. try with:

```
p:first-letter{font-size:48px;}
```